# Separately color all rows for unique clients listed in one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, conditional-formatting

I am a relative Excel noob, and to that end, forget about Excel macros. I'm here because this seems to be where the GOATs congregate, and I really need some help.

I have an enormous data set that lists all of the services given to thousands of clients. I have to manually analyze and clean all of this data for individual clients due to human error/judgment, because life is pain.

For ease of my analysis - by making it easier on my eyes and my brain to analyze all the services rendered to a unique client - I am trying to highlight all rows associated with every other client listed in one column. White and one other color is fine - I'm just looking for something that will consistently differentiate all rows that belong to one client. I have columns going from A to AE, and about ~32,000 rows (and around ~2,000 clients.) Here is what I'm looking to do:

[This is what I would like to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGmjW.png)

Could someone please explain how to achieve this? I will be forever grateful!!!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the post
[Excel: Conditional formatting for clusters of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492425/excel-conditional-formatting-for-clusters-of-values),
here is a quote of a very simple method proposed in the
[answer by teylyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16493622/165358):

> If you want alternating colours, try this:
>
> Format the whole range in blue. Enter this formula into a helper
> column, for example column B, starting in row 2 and copied down.
>
> ```
> =IF(A2=A1,B1,IF(B1=1,0,1))
> ```
>
> Then select the rows and add conditional formatting with this formula
>
> ```
> =$B2
> ```
>
> Select green as a cell fill. See screenshot. You can hide column B.
>
> [image]